# Update MySQL table with foreach()

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

When I try and update my table instead of incrementing over the array of urls, what is printed to the table is just the last entry in the url array.

When I echo the `$url` I can tell it loops through the array properly. When I echo `$currentId` is increments properly. Why doesn't the query enter each `$url` on a row in my table. What is happening here that I don't understand?

```
$currentId = 1;
foreach($pages as $url)
{
    $query = "UPDATE pageurls SET url='$url' WHERE id='currentId'";
    mysql_query($query);
    echo($url.'<br/>');
    $currentId++;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Instead of

```
$query = "UPDATE pageurls SET url='$url' WHERE id='currentId'";
```

...which looks for an id matching the *string* "currentId", try...

```
$query = "UPDATE pageurls SET url='".mysql_real_escape_string($url).
         "' WHERE id=".$currentId;
```

Since you're generating currentId by yourself, it's safe, but you should really escape $url using mysql_real_escape_string.

Edit: As @Topener points out, I missed a $ before currentId, edited to fix that.

Comment: @Topener Actually, the manual states; "This function must always (with few exceptions) be used to make data safe before sending a query to MySQL.", even a string you create yourself could include a "'" character.

Comment: @Topener: This will not still throw an error.  If you're referring to the fact that he left out the single quotes, it was probably done on purpose, given that a column named `id` is 9 times out of 10 going to be numeric in any given schema, and this is supported in the OP by this line: `$currentId = 1`.

Comment: Ah you changed your answer, don't mind my comment above. First it was "query".currentId (Without `$`)

Comment: @drrcknlsn Actually I had a typo, I forgot the $ before currentId, I edited to fix that before I saw the comment.

Comment: Should also try and look into using prepared statements to avoid SQL injection exploits. Just a thought ;)

Comment: Sorry about the 'currentId' string. I don't have that in my code I just pasted it wrong. Sorry. But $query = "UPDATE pageurls SET url='".mysql_real_escape_string($url)."' WHERE id='".$currentId; still adds only the last url in the array to all the id's in the mysql table (it is only 21 rows.)

Comment: If you echo $query for every line, you should see quickly why it's updating wrong. Can't see anything wrong in the code. Is $pages correct when you enter this code?

Answer (score 5):

You are comparing a string: `WHERE id='currentId'`

Should be a variable `WHERE id='$currentId'`

Answer (score 2):

currentId is used as a string, not a a variable.

Also, you should make sure you escape those values with [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)

Comment: It is not really about user input, it is about making sure what mysql considers to be a special character will be handled correctly. It is a great habit to have.

Comment: @Topener: Since the system needs to be programmed by someone, it's still "user" input (especially if you employ junior coders). Still, it would probably be saner to a) use a correct type (e.g. `(int)$currentId`) or b) parametrised queries, than to blindly cast everything to string.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in this line:

```
$query = "UPDATE pageurls SET url='$url' WHERE id='currentId'";
```

I would change it like this:

```
$query = "UPDATE pageurls SET url='".$url."' WHERE id=".$currentId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're properly escaping the variables being used in the query (looks like `intval()` for `id` / `$currentId` if that's coming from user input or any external source, and `mysql_real_escape_string()` for `url`, as @Louis said).  Then interpolate them into the query, and don't quote `$currentId` if it is indeed an integer.

```
$currentId = 1;

foreach( $pages as $url ) {

    $query = "UPDATE pageurls SET url = '{$url}' WHERE id = {$currentId}";

    mysql_query( $query );

    echo( $url . '<br/>' );

    $currentId++;

}
// foreach
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using strings instead of variable !

This query is awefull ! It will take you a lot of ressources for nothing if you update a lot of rows !

Have a look at: "[Update Multiple Rows With Different Values and a Single SQL Query](http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-and-a-single-sql-query/)"

Comment: Only 21 rows because I am trying to figure out why echo prints the correct thing (thus I know the variables are getting the right values each time through the loop) but the mysql table only prints the last value of url 21 times.